# This file in the editor in not runnable intelliJ idea using java

Tags: java, intellij-idea, compilation

I installed intelliJ idea for the first time to code in java, before this IDE I used VS Code for the development and compilation. After installing I opened previously written code folders in IntelliJ which has the run button in grey showing "this file in the editor is not runnable".

[this is the directory structure with the code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sZwyu.png)

Previously in VS Code these files were easily compiled but in IntelliJ idea I have no clue why it is happening.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should create a `Java project` using the IntelliJ idea first, so it will create all the necessary files for the IDE to recognize it as a native Java project.

Then, you can copy and paste your existing file codes into the `src` folder, respecting the Java module organization of:
`src > main > java > your Files/Packages`

Also, while creating your Java project, I recommend you to create it using `Gradle`, it will simplify a lot to maintaining the project dependencies.

**References:**

- [Create your first Java application](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/creating-and-running-your-first-java-application.html)
- [Learn Idea features](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/feature-trainer.html)
- [Getting Started with Gradle](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/getting-started-with-gradle.html)

---

#### VS Code vs. IntelliJ Idea for Java projects

- VS Code is a rich text editor like Sublime Text and Atom;

  - *You can turn VS Code into an IDE like, using plugins.*
- IntelliJ Idea is a thoroughly professional IDE (Integrated development environment).

For Java projects, I recommend using IntelliJ Idea, however for a general-purpose code practice, go for VS Code for sure, its flexibility is incredible.

- [IntelliJ IDEA vs. Microsoft Visual Studio Code](https://www.trustradius.com/compare-products/intellij-idea-vs-microsoft-visual-studio-code)

Answer (score 0):

You could right-click the "Sorting" folder, and choose `Mark Directory as | Sources Root`. Then you should be able to run that Java code.
In IntelliJ IDEA, the folder including all Java packages should be marked as a source root to make it work. See here for details: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/content-roots.html

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. What you need to do is on the top of the editor, click 'Current File' selecetion like twice and it will appear. [image]

Answer (score 0):

I may happen because of missing SDK. I got same error because I set no SDK for the project. I could run after my set a correct SDK.

Answer (score -1):

Make sure the entire code is inside the

`public static void main(String[] args){---Your code---}` method.

[Code example image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/caKyh.png)